# Is there a file manager with file search that doesn't break xubuntu desktop

Tags: search, .desktop, filemanager

I am looking of a file manager for Xubuntu that would:
(1) Be file search capable. The default combination Thunar+Catfish is can only search files, but cannot manipulate those. Catfish fails to shift+select multiple files from the results
(2) Nautilus natively searching files, but it breaks xfce desktop each time I run it (background picture is reset each time I launch Nautilus)
(3) Don't be bloated with unnecessary Unity like visuals
Is there combination of desktop manager+file manager with native file search support working out of box?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if these will do what you want, but I have a few suggestions: Dolphin (from the KDE project), PCManFM, Caja (from MATE) and even a command line file manager, Midnight Commander.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install Krusader.  Krusader is an advanced file manager for KDE and other desktops, that has advanced search capabilities. To install it, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install krusader
```